# Why Single Click don't works on RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> I have a simple RecyclerView with an Interface that is linked to the activity. The **Issue** is the **items in the recyclerView need double click in order to perform an action.**

This is the `AllProductsAdapter` Code :

```
public class AllProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllProductsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

RecyclerViewClickInterfaceNew recyclerViewClickInterface;
List<ProductsModel> productsModelList;
Context context;

public AllProductsAdapter(List<ProductsModel> productsModelList, Context context, RecyclerViewClickInterfaceNew recyclerViewClickInterface) {

    this.productsModelList = productsModelList;
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerViewClickInterface = recyclerViewClickInterface;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AllProductsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false);
    return new AllProductsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllProductsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    ProductsModel productsModel = productsModelList.get(position);
    PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(context)
            .load(productsModel.getProduct_image())
            .into(holder.catImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productsModelList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView catImage;
    TextView catName;
    CardView categoryCard;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        catImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catImage);
        catName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catName);
        categoryCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryCard);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (recyclerViewClickInterface != null)
                    recyclerViewClickInterface.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> This is my `RecyclerViewClickInterfaceNew` :

```
    public interface RecyclerViewClickInterfaceNew {

    void onItemClick(View view , int position);
    void onLongItemClick(int position);

}
```

> This is my MainActivity code :

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view , int position) {
    ImageView img= view.findViewById(R.id.catImage);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(AllProductsList.this, "Imgclciked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

> Here in the MainActivity, the `Toast shows after clicking 2 times on the Image.` How can i fix it to a normal single click ? Please let me know your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From this code

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(View view , int position) {

//when different item is FIRST clicked, a new instance of catImage is produced 
    ImageView img= view.findViewById(R.id.catImage);

//the img onClick is set here to require a second click
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(AllProductsList.this, "Imgclciked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

For each new item on the Recycler View, you reset the click handling.

I'll suggest you set the onClickListener ON the ViewHolder. It's not the best practice but it'll suffice for your code

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because of you are using NestedScrollView ,
you should add this line to your recyclerview

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```